# Is there a Vagrant box that simulates a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, vagrant, raspbian

I am looking at evaluating a tool-chain for programming ARM chips with a Raspberry Pi and I would like to run a Vagrant box that simulates a Raspberry Environment.

Answer (score 8):

There is no Vagant box to simulate the RPi because as @Cerin said Virtual Box (which Vagrant uses) doesn't support Rapsberry Pi architecture (ARM).
But there is a docker that provide a shell to a Raspbian image running on qemu.

Look here for a quick setup : https://gist.github.com/Manu343726/ca0ceb224ea789415387

Note that this guide is made for arch linux. You can do the same with debian/ubuntu changing `yaourt -S` call with `sudo apt install`

Answer (score 0):

There exists the [rpi-build-and-boot](https://github.com/twobitcircus/rpi-build-and-boot) or the older [raspberry-devbox](https://github.com/Asquera/raspberry-devbox) Vagrant development box for Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I noticed it but looking at the Vagrant file it uses "box.vm.box = "ubuntu-10.04.3-server-amd64-asq"" . Is that the same as Rasbian?

Comment: No it's not the same. It's an image which can be used for development and cross-compiling for the raspberry pi. See also [this issue](https://github.com/Asquera/raspberry-devbox/issues/1)

Comment: Or maybe [this one](https://github.com/twobitcircus/rpi-build-and-boot) can help you. Its also more up to date.

Comment: Note, neither of those simulate the Raspberry Pi. They each use Virtualbox which does not support ARM, and therefore cannot simulate the Pi's ARM processor. It looks like they just set up a cross-compilation environment, but that's not the same thing as simulating the Pi.